# How can I get vim-surround to automatically indent surrounded HTML code?

Tags: plugin-vim-surround

I am wanting to wrap the `<h2>` and the `<div>` blocks below and surround them both with another `<div>`

```
<body>

    <h2>Im a heading</h2>
    <div class="row">
        im some content
    </div>

</body>
```

From normal mode, I am entering `-- VISUAL LINE --`

- <kbd>V</kbd>, select block, <kbd>S</kbd> (enter surround mode), then type `<div>`

vim-surround successfully wraps the block, but loses all indenting, e.g:

```
<body>    

<div>
<h2>Im a heading</h2>
<div class="row">
im some content
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

I notice elsewhere, people are saying capital `S` tells vim-surround "surround AND indent", but for me capital `S` only enables vim-surround and lowercase `s` doesnt work at all.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13349701/4668401) suggests there is some possible setup required to enable the indenting behaviour for <kbd>S</kbd>.
Or is it an operating system specific issue? (My OS is Ubuntu 14.04)

How can I get vim-surround's automatic indenting to work?

Comment: Might have something to do with tags you're surrounding them with: [How do I get vim to auto indent block-level html elements?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3645/205) ... Nope. Vim indents it just fine for me on Ubuntu 14.04, patch level 843 (pi-rho's PPA).

Comment: @muru I struggled to believe it would not work for block - but that it would work for inline elements, thanks for eliminating that as a possibility. I have got a solution. will post an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workable solution by changing the following vim core settings.

```
:filetype indent on
:set smartindent
```

In my case I was editing an HTML file - which vim had no trouble detecting as the correct filetype, but if you were editing any other HTML-containing file that vim didn't recognise correctly, you may need to add:

```
:set filetype=html
```

Those changes enabled visually selecting a block of text and hitting <kbd>=</kbd> to automatically indent HTML tags correctly.
After that vim-surround also automatically indented when surrounding code - similar to pressing <kbd>=</kbd>.

#### More background

Reading [`:help filetype`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#%3Afiletype) gave an excellent overview/introduction to what was going on.

For example, to see what your current `filetype` setting is:

```
To see the current status, type: 
        :filetype
The output looks something like this: 
        filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:OFF
```

Comment: You didn't have `filetype indent on`? O.o I usually have `filetype plugin indent on` so that all three (filetype detection, filetype-based plugin and filetype-based indentation are enabled).

Comment: @muru I wasnt explicitly setting it in my `.vimrc` - other than that I dont know how to check whether `filetype indent` is  `on` or `off`. I just know when I applied `:filetype indent on` and  `:set smartindent ` auto indent started working